# Passing NSManagedObject between threads

Tags: ios, core-data

I know it's not thread safe to pass NSManagedObject from one thread to another thread, we have to pass the object ID and get back the object by objectWithID in the target thread, but I don't want to pass the object ID across thread, can I get the object by calling objectWithID on the target context first and then pass it to the target thread.

```
let parserContext: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager().newPrivateManagedObjectContext()
let mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager().mainManagedObjectContext()

var object: NSManagedObject?
parserContext.performBlockAndWait {  
  object = mainContext.objectWithID(model.objectID)
}
return object // return to main thread
```

Comment: No, you can not. ```parserContext.performBlockAndWait``` is called on its private queue, you should not access ```maincontext``` from uit since it runs on main thread. You may set ``parserContext`` to be child of ``mainContext`` and then simply get any object

Comment: You can't call the block on one context and then access a different context, but if you call the block and access the same context from the other thread...

Comment: How about I first call 

mainContext.performBlockAndWait {
   object = mainContext.objectWithID(model.objectID)
}
and then return the object to the main thread?